# Bash script check for successful curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bash script that runs every five minutes to get an updated file from a ftp server. I know what time they generate the file which is every 5 minutes starting at 0 minutes of each hour. It usually takes them 30 seconds to generate the file and so I have mine offset by 1 minute (running every 5 minutes starting at 1 minute of each hour). However, there are times when their server bogs down and takes longer (sometimes minutes) to generate their file and it only takes about 13 seconds for me to download and process the file. When this happens I end up getting basically the first portion of the file and not the rest. Is there a way to verify that what I just downloaded matches what is on the ftp server? I was thinking maybe there was a way to check that the filesize of what I downloaded matches what is on the ftp server. Is that possible? My other thought was that if that is possible, depending on how quickly it can compare those two files, a delay may need to be built in to ensure it has time to for the file on the ftp server to have more data written to it if it is still in progress. Thoughts/suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would instead suggest changing the server-side process.  The file should not be built "into" the publicly-accessible file; it should be built into a temporary file and then moved over the existing file.  This will ensure that clients either see the old file or the new file in their entirety, never a partially-built file.

Comment: Don't overwrite the file, use some kind of sequence to name them

Comment: While I agree with you, cdhowie, I have no control over the server. I can make recommendations but it is up to them as to whether they will make that change.